# PlantUML: Is there a way to disable the vertical alignment of elements on the same level of the hierarchy of a class diagram?

Tags: uml, plantuml

In Plant UML I have a couple of classes where I need to specify a large number of attributes in one of the classes, but this causes a large vertical gap between that class' siblings and its sibling's children.

Is there a way I can tell the rendering engine not to care about vertically aligning two subclasses if they don't share a direct parent?

Minimal example of my class hierarchy

```
parent <|-- child1
parent <|-- child2
child2 <|-- child2a

class child1 {
    i
    have
    a
    lot
    of
    different
    fields
    that
    need
    to
    be
    included
    which
    makes
    my
    box
    very
    long
}
```

Desired output:
[image: An output where child2a can be displayed directly below child2 instead of being pushed down below the height of child1]

Observed output:
[image: An output with a large amount of empty space between child2 and child2a, forcing child2a to be below the height of child1]

Answer (score 1):

The best I could get is close, but not exactly what you wanted:

```
@startuml
together {
class child1 {
    i
    have
    a
    lot
    of
    different
    fields
    that
    need
    to
    be
    included
    which
    makes
    my
    box
    very
    long
}

class child2
}

child2 <|- child2a
parent <|-- child1
parent <|- child2
@enduml
```

Explanation: group child1 and child2 together, but child1 is vertically displaced (on a different rank). child2 and child2a are horizontally displaced (on the same rank). I don't think it's possible to do what you ask, because of the way ranking works in GraphViz, which is the engine for PlantUML.

[image: PlantUML diagram with link to live editor]